# OC cluster UP on Fedora not started correctly

Tags: openshift, fedora

I am trying to run openshift on Fedora 36 using Origin-Client or OC.
I have updated fedora to the latest version.
[image: DNF update]
I have installed oc .
whenever I tried to do `oc cluster up`

it shows below error :

```
[root@fedora ridhoswasta]# oc cluster up
Getting a Docker client ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 is available ...
Checking type of volume mount ...
Determining server IP ...
Checking if OpenShift is already running ...
Checking for supported Docker version (=>1.22) ...
Checking if insecured registry is configured properly in Docker ...
Checking if required ports are available ...
Checking if OpenShift client is configured properly ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 is available ...
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.11 ...
I0825 12:11:14.411027   50887 flags.go:30] Running "create-kubelet-flags"
I0825 12:11:16.391985   50887 run_kubelet.go:49] Running "start-kubelet"
I0825 12:11:17.200056   50887 run_self_hosted.go:181] Waiting for the kube-apiserver to be ready ...
E0825 12:16:17.201364   50887 run_self_hosted.go:571] API server error: Get "https://127.0.0.1:8443/healthz?timeout=32s": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: connect: connection refused ()
Error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Then I checked the logs for kubelet container it shows :

```
Flag --tls-cipher-suites has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Flag --tls-cipher-suites has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Flag --tls-cipher-suites has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Flag --tls-cipher-suites has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Flag --tls-min-version has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Flag --tls-private-key-file has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Flag --pod-manifest-path has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Flag --file-check-frequency has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Flag --cluster-dns has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
I0825 05:13:19.249680   51788 server.go:417] Version: v1.11.0+d4cacc0
I0825 05:13:19.249928   51788 plugins.go:97] No cloud provider specified.
F0825 05:13:19.253892   51788 server.go:261] failed to run Kubelet: mountpoint for cpu not found
```

I have tried to reinstall docker with latest version but still I face this issue.
Could someone give me another thing to try?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`oc cluster up` is using the deprecated version of OpenShift, this has been superseded by OpenShift Local now: https://developers.redhat.com/products/openshift-local/overview. Although OpenShift Local uses a good deal more resources than `oc cluster up` ever did. There's a spiritual successor that might be worth checking out, and that's MicroShift: https://microshift.io/